# How to add "ui.bootstrap" dependency to existing bower components for achieving "typeahead" feature?

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-typeahead

How to add "ui.bootstrap" dependency to existing bower components for achieving  "typeahead" feature?

i follow the given link(https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/) for the purpose of  my auto complete suggestions while doing search an item Asynchronously and it needs ui.bootstrap for achieving this feature so how can i add this feature to my existing project bower.json file

My bower.json

```
{
  "name": "project-ui",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "dependencies": {
    "angular": "^1.3.0",
    "bootstrap": "^3.2.0",
    "angular-animate": "^1.3.0",
    "angular-cookies": "^1.3.0",
    "angular-resource": "^1.3.0",
    "angular-route": "^1.3.0",
    "angular-sanitize": "^1.3.0",
    "angular-touch": "^1.3.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "angular-mocks": "^1.3.0"
  },
  "appPath": "app",
  "moduleName": "projectUiApp"
}
```

Comment: Actually i am using "yo"man for my project

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the docs https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/blob/master/README.md#install-with-bower

Running this command will install and add angular-bootstrap to dev dependencies

```
bower install angular-bootstrap --save-dev
```

and then according to https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/getting_started

> As soon as you've got all the files downloaded and included in your page
>   you just need to declare a dependency on the ui.bootstrap module:

`angular.module('myModule', ['ui.bootstrap']);`

Comment: where can i run this command ,i mean within my project folder where node modules kept..

Comment: if you do not know how to use bower, you can simply download js files from the site https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/

Comment: btw, bowser install should be called in the same directory with bower.json file

Comment: Yes , i did it but i got another error while doing mvn clean install for my ui

Comment: i.e  Failed to execute goal com.github.trecloux:yeoman-maven-plugin:0.4:build (default) on project